# iPad-only CSS + Desktop CSS Conflict?

Tags: html, iphone, css, ipad

Okay so I want to have three separate CSS files. One for desktops and larger laptops. One for iPads in landscape. And one for iPads in portrait.

**Current CSS:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="css/ipad-landscape.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 1025px)" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
```

For some reason, only the style.css is loaded when I check on Screenfly: http://quirktools.com/screenfly/. When I lower the screen resolution to a netbook or iPad, style.css stops being used but ipad-landscape.css (when the screen is in landscape) is not loaded in its place. Currently, the contents of ipad-landscape.css and style.css are the same so there is no chance that one just doesn't work. Is it possible to use more than one CSS file for screen size differentiation? If so, how do I fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should have just one css file, and rather use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Second, `orientation:landscape` is information that devices send to the browser, and I'm pretty sure screenfly is simply an iframe to view styles. Things like width/height will work, but checking orientation won't.

Try testing with iOS Simulator in Xcode (if you're using Mac OS X), or testing on an actual device, and it should work.